# What's the usage of -exec xargs and -print0?

Tags: shell

I think these are the common ways of passing the result of one command to the next one, as inputs.

How do these three work? Or what are some websites/URLs?

Answer (score 29):

First things to type:

```
man find

man xargs
```

The `find` command prints results to standard output by default, so the `-print` option is normally not needed, but `-print0` separates the filenames with a 0 (NULL) byte so that names containing spaces or newlines can be interpreted correctly.

The `-exec` option is something you can use instead of xargs - the find command executes a command for each item it finds.

The `xargs` command reads space- or newline-separated strings (typically from the **find** command, but they could come from anywhere) and executes some command for each string.
If xargs is run with a **-0** option, it'll expect NULL-separated strings as output by `find ... -print0`

The advantage of xargs is that it can group the strings together, so that it only executes a command once or twice instead of *n* times.

So in the normal usage:

```
find start_directory -name '*.txt' | xargs ls -l
```

**find** would list the filenames, and **xargs** would issue commands like:

```
ls -l file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt ... fileN.txt
```

which is faster than having your find command issuing:

```
ls -l file1.txt
ls -l file2.txt
ls -l file3.txt
ls -l ...
ls -l fileN.txt
```

Answer (score 11):

Note that xargs is no more needed with current find implementations that probably all support this POSIX syntax:

```
find directory -name '*.txt' -exec ls -l {} +
```

which is simpler and slightly faster than the xargs variant.

```
find directory -name '*.txt' | xargs ls -l
```

Comment: xargs uses far fewer resources than 'find -exec'

Comment: That's the other way around. Piping to xargs will use slightly more resources than -exec. You probably overlook the "+" terminator.

Comment: xargs can use more than one processor... this is much more helpful when the command is more complicated than 'ls'... possibly something like a file conversion.

Comment: @JosephFitzgerald Gnu xargs has this extension indeed but other xargs implementations might not as it isn't specified by POSIX. That was probably more relevant ten years ago than now though.

Answer (score 2):

See the following articles:

[Linux and Unix find command tutorial with examples](https://shapeshed.com/unix-find/)
[xargs: How To Control and Use Command Line Arguments](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/)

Comment: at least one of those links is dead. Its better to just post the relevant code sample as well.

Comment: @user5359531: The dead link was replaced. And I cannot reproduce such voluminous tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Make two files by

touch 'my file1' myfile2

find . -name "m*" | xargs ls -l (error)

find . -name "m*" -print0 | xargs --null ls - l (right outcome)

-print0 seperate the file names with space